# Specific Issue related to variable referencing

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables, reference

Now, I want to make it clear that I do not want to include the variable `b` as an argument of the function `g`. Is there any other way I could go about rewriting this code, given that g is called recursively? Even mentioning b = 0 and calling it as a global does not seem to help with the reference assignment error.

```
global b
b = 0
def g(x):
    if b < x:
        for i in range(10):
            if u == i:
                b += 1
                g(x)    #g is called recursively
for u in range(20):
    b = 5
    g(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# that is from MSeifert(voted is correct), @Chalid
b = 0
first = []
second = []
def g(x):
    global b  # So python knows you use the global variable!
    first.append(b)
    if b < x:
        for i in range(10):
            if u == i:
                b += 1
                g(x)

for u in range(20):
    b = 5
    g(7)


# my solution is without any global variable
# and the result matching the expectation

def g(x,b):
    second.append(b)
    if b < x:
        for i in range(10):
            if u == i:
                b += 1
                g(x,b)    #g is called recursively
b = 5
for u in range(20):
  g(7,b)

print len(first), len(second)
print first
print second

40 40
[5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: But then every time I run the function `g`, I'll have to give it some value in place of b right? which might actually mess up the code

Comment: if b is relevant for g yes, i mean you increasing b by one, than you are calling g with the last result of b

Answer (score 1):

`global` is used when you explicitly want to use and update a `global` variable. So you need to use `global b` inside your function instead of outside:

```
b = 0

def g(x):
    global b  # So python knows you use the global variable!
    if b < x:
        for i in range(10):
            if u == i:
                b += 1
                g(x)
                
for u in range(20):
    b = 5
    g(7)
```

Because you use `b += 1` inside your `g` function you need to declare `b` as `global`. Otherwise you get a `UnboundLocalError`:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment

See also the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> **What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?**
>
> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring `global` for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if `global` was required for all `global` references, you’d be using `global` all the time. You’d have to declare as `global` every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the `global` declaration for identifying side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

It might make people's hair stand on end but you could add `b` as an attribute to `g`.

```
def g(x):
    If g.b > x:
        ...

g.b = 5
....
```